# What are the differences between "their country" and "their own country"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What are the differences between "**their country**" and "**their own country**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion of **own** merely acts to emphasise or intensify the association with or sense of possession of the object or place concerned.

People tend to use **own** for things or places that are important to them or that they have created although this is a trend rather than a rule.

So while we speak of **my shoes, my parents, my home, my school and my doctor** we tend to include **own** in such expressions as **all my own work, my own efforts, my own idea** when we want to emphasise our unique part, our creative inspiration or particular ownership.

**Their country** is not an emotive phrase in itself. It merely refers to the country that "they" come from.

**Their own country** is more likely to be used of a territory or area special or sacred to a community, clan or tribe such as the Australian aboriginals or First Nations of America.